# Creating x amount of arrays inside an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble managing to create x amount of arrays inside a larger array.
As in, I have little to no idea how to do this. What my program would do is ask
for an integer input from the user, where x= that input, and then create a while loop, with a loop counter, that would create x amount of arrays inside one larger array (i.e. 30 arrays inside one larger array). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Edit: I have been thinking and writing out ways to solve this problem for about an hour, but have yet to actually conceive of any code or concrete ways to solve this. I am still very new to Java, and am slightly out of my depth here. Again, any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Show some semblance of an attempt at this problem before someone will help, please.

Comment: What's wrong with using String[][]?

Comment: Don't use arrays. Use Lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a new `array` of `array`s, by using

`<Type>[][] largeArray= new <Type>[Amount of smaller arrays][];`

Then read the input from the user. Then, using a `for` loop, create a new smaller `array` in each iteration

`<Type>[] smallerArray = new <Type>[Size of smaller array];`

and put that array at the index that the loop is on:

`largeArray[i] = smallerArray;`

An example of this being done for a `String` type is like such:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String[][] largeArray = new String[100][];
    int x = 30;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        String [] smallerArray = new String[10];
        largeArray[i] = smallerArray;
    }

}
```